# Change Activity Log table name

Tags: php, laravel

I installed [spatie/activitylog](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog) for logging user activity,

the default table name in this package is `activity_log` I want change the table name to `users_activity_log`

I created a model and named `Activity` but not work:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Models;

class Activity extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "user_activity_log";
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: A wild guess says you'll at least need to extend [packages activity model](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/blob/master/src/Models/Activity.php) first. Looking at documentation you will also need to update packages config file to tell it to use your model instead. Refer to this line: `'activity_model' => \Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity::class` in documentation.

Comment: @devk Thanks, Yes I trying to extend with created model, but not work, I'm newbie in Laravel and maybe I do it in wrong way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution,

1- Create a model : `php artisan make:model Activity`

2- put this code in your model (change `$table` with your table name):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Activity extends \Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity
{
    //
    protected $table = "user_activity_log";
}
```

3- publish the `logactivity` config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Activitylog\ActivitylogServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

4- change the `activity_model` in `laravel-activitylog.php` :

```
'activity_model' => \App\Activity::class
```

**DON'T FORGET to change table name in migration file**

Thanks to @devk